# How do I fetch all the Open Graph videos watched by the user or associated with an application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Apologies if this has been answered before.

I know how to get the watches actions from a given user:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.watches

My question is how do you get the videos that were watched? Doing so by traversing the list I get back in video.watches would be ridiculous because there can be duplicates and such.

In the open graph documentation it says you can do something like /me/recipebox:cook/recipes

(taken from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/ - Retrieving a set of Objects)

But I can't seem to figure out how to apply that to video.watches (the type is "video.other")

Getting the list of videos watched across the entire application would be fine as well.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The call `me/video.watches` should give you all watches across all applications. Most likely you have the `user_actions.video` permission missing. It shouldn't return duplicates. If it does consider filing a bug.